# Every AVL tree can be colored to be a red-black tree

Tags: induction, avl-trees, red-black-trees

I want to prove any AVL tree can be turnt into a red-black tree by coloring nodes appropriately.
Let $h$ be the height of a subtree of an AVL tree.
It is given that such a coloring is constrained by these cases:

1. $h$ even $\implies$ black height $=$ $\frac{h}{2} + 1$, root node black
2. $h$ odd $\implies$ black height $=$  $\frac{h+1}{2}$, root node red

After that the root node is colored black.

---

I'm trying to prove this inductively. Let's start with the **base case** $h=1$. Then there is only one node (the root node) and it gets colored black (using case 2) which yields a valid red-black tree.

Now suppose the statement is true for some $h \geq 1$. Then for any node $u$ in the AVL tree, the height difference between their children is less than $1$. That is, for an AVL tree of height $h+1$ either both subtrees of the root node have height $h$ or one has height $h-1$.

By the induction hypothesis we know how to color the subtree of height $h$, depending on the parity of $h$. I'm unsure if I should use strong induction instead because it is *not* given in the hypothesis how to color a subtree of height $h-1$.

If we *would* know how to color both subtrees, then consider the following cases:

1. $h+1$ is even

   - one subtree has height $h$, the other height $h-1$
   - both subtrees have height $h$
2. $h+1$ is odd

   - one subtree has height $h$, the other height $h-1$
   - both subtrees have height $h$

For case 1.1 we would get
$$
  \begin{align*}
\quad & h+1 &\text{even} \\
\implies \quad & h &\text{odd} \\
\implies \quad & \text{black height} = \frac{h+1}{2} \\
\implies \quad & h-1 &\text{even} \\
\implies \quad & \text{black height} = \frac{(h-1)}{2} + 1 = \frac{h+1}{2}
  \end{align*}
$$

So their black heights differ by $1$. How would I take that into consideration?

Comment: I do not understand your initial assumption. If $h$ is even then the black height equals $\frac {h+1}2$. But that's not an integer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've interchanged them. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Same problem in your last paragraph?

Comment: So, now after correction in the last paragraph both cases we have the same outcome. Do you still have a problem? Or does it move to the other case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is](https://hub.darcs.net/dolio/agda-share/browse/AVL.agda) a computer verification of your method.

The height discrepancies occur when we are making a red root, in which case the shorter child with the reduced black height would also have a red root. Since there can't be two consecutive red nodes, we need to turn the shorter child black, which increases its black height to match the taller child.